# How to put several QImage in a QGraphicsView?

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

I have a scene where several items are added. The problem is that when the items are displayed, they are overlapping. Is there any way to indicate in the `QGraphicsView` or `QGraphicsScene` the position where each item should appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to use `QGraphicsItem::setPos()` method.
I suppose you added a `QGraphicsPixmapItem`, so it could look like :

```
QGraphicsScene *scene = ... ; // your scene
QImage image = ... ; // the QImage you want to add to the scene
QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(image) ;

// add image item to the scene
QGraphicsPixmapItem * imageItem = scene->addPixmap(pixmap) ;

// modify item's position in scene coordinates
QPointF imagePos = ... ; // whatever scene pos you want
imageItem->setPos(imagePos) ;
```